# Add shp attribute data to column with python

Tags: python, cursor, arcgis, arcpy

if feature column in table is ferry crossing then I need to add Yes to the Ferry column that I have already added to the table. If feature column does not say ferry crossing I need to add No to the ferry column. Here is the chunk of code that I am having an issue with. Any suggestions? Yes I'm new to python, any advice or hints would be greatly appreciated as it will help me learn. Cheers.

```
#need to update FERRY column with yes or no values if ferry crossing is available in feature field
delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, "FERRY")
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FERRY"])
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] == "ferry crossing":
        cursor.updateRow("FERRY")
        print "YES"
    if row[0] is not "ferry crossing":
        cursor.updateRow("FERRY")
        print "NO"

del row
del cursor

#if feature is ferry crossing == YES in FERRY field
#if feature is not ferry crossing == NO in FERRY field
```

Comment: Please define better the context you are using Python in, are you coding a script into some kind of application? Please specify in your question.

Comment: I'm coding a script for arcgis using arcpy. I didn't include all of the code of the part that I have already gotten working. Maybe I should have put this in the GIS side of stack exchange idk...

Comment: Yeah, I think is better. Try also to introduce better in the post the context in which you run into this problem.

Comment: maybe in this situation I should have added all the script. I thought it might be nice to add the part I was having problems with so there wouldn't be as much info to consider.

Comment: Usually is better to give as much information as possible without been chaotic. Move the question to the GIS stack with more explanations and code and you will probably find some help there.

Comment: Cross posted to http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/179737/115

Comment: In future, please do not cross-post questions. Post your question on one Stack Exchange site, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab both fields in your cursor: the `feature` field for your test and the `FERRY` field that you want to update. Then, your existing code will properly test, but you'll need to modify it to perform the update. Use the list positions of the fields to access them in the row object.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FEATURE", "FERRY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "ferry crossing": # test the FEATURE field
            row[1] = "FERRY" # set the FERRY field
            print "YES"
        else:
            print "NO"
        cursor.updateRow(row) # commit the changes
```

Comment: Evan you make it seem so easy. Thanks for your help.